# Symfony and Doctrine 1.2.2: How can i get the SQL clause of a Doctrine_Query object?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

i have this code:

```
  $this->lista_miembros = $this->filtro->buildQuery($valores_query);
  var_dump($this->lista_miembros);
```

var_dump outputs a Doctrine_Query object:

> object(Doctrine_Query)[121]
>   protected '_subqueryAliases' => 
>       array

I tried getSql() ...

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('u.id')
    ->from('User u')
    ->whereIn('u.id', array(1, 3, 4, 5));
echo $q->getSql();
```

..but I dont have that getSql() function!

So how can i get the SQL clause of that Doctrine_Query object?

Javi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo $q->getSqlQuery();
```