# ZF / Doctrine question

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

We are using Zend Framework with Doctrine for a project. I have installed the application using Doctrine ORM.

When I'm echoing the statement, it prints only the "FROM User u WHERE u.username = ?"

What is the "Doctrine_Query::create()"?

Any library is required ?

```
public function loginAction(){      
    $error_messages = array();

    $params = $this->_request->getParams();
    if($_POST)
    {
        $params = $this->_request->getParams();

        $username = $params['username'];
        $password = $params['password'];

        $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('User u')
            ->where('u.username = ?',$username);
        echo    $query;
        exit;
        $user = $query->execute()->getFirst();

        //Authentication !
        $authexAdapter = new Application_Auth_exAdapter($user,$password);           
        $authResult = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->authenticate($authexAdapter);

        if(!$authResult->isValid()){
            $error_messages = $authResult->getMessages();
        } else {
            //sucess!

                    $this->_redirect('account/setup');

        }
    }
    $this->view->error_messages = $error_messages;
}
```

Comment: Possibly the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772902/symfony-and-doctrine-1-2-2-how-can-i-get-the-sql-clause-of-a-doctrine-query-obje

Comment: The `exit;` in your code would definitely stop it from showing anything after the `echo $query;` line.

Answer (score 1):

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
```

It creates the query that will be run to find your objects. When echoing the object, it prints the string query that was created.

> Any library is required ?

Well, Doctrine ORM.

Did you read any manual, or follow a tutorial ? It seems like you don't even know what's going on ?